# sql server to store sessions state /time out

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-2, session-state

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="100" defaultUrl="~/" name="Auth"/>
</authentication>
```

AND

```
<sessionState timeout ="1"></sessionState>
```

Among this 2 which determines the time out period of active log in, if a I am using sql server 
to store sessions state?

(me in asp.net mvc 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="100" defaultUrl="~/" name="Auth"/>
</authentication>
```

The above code will determine your logged in user's session time. This means that after 100 minutes of inactivity, a user will be prompted to login again. The default timeout is 30 Minutes if not specified.

```
<sessionState timeout ="1"></sessionState>
```

The session timeout configuration setting applies only to ASP.NET pages. Changing the session timeout value does not affect the session time-out for ASP pages.

Comment: did u mean the deference between ASP.NET and classical ASP?

Comment: No, Can you read answer again carefully, Actually there are two places where we mention Session timeOut, one for logined user and other Session user that interact with website pages.

Answer (score 1):

FormsAuthentication and Session are two different mechanisms, which use two different cookies.  There timeouts are independent.

If you want to know when a Session expires (which you're storing in Sql or otherwise) then the SessionState timeout determines that.